# WorksheetFunction.Trim Removing Leading Zeroes

Tags: excel, vba

I see a lot of questions asking how to remove leading zeroes, but I'm in a bit of a bind trying to preserve mine.

I'm trying to run a general purpose Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim macro on a series of different worksheets with mixed data types. One of these columns will have different length numbers, some of which have leading zeroes and I have a column of dates. I can preserve the zeroes by formatting cell by cell as Text when run, but that seems to break my dates. I've haven't had much success only turning it to Text if the cell doesn't contain a date, having tried:

```
If Cell.NumberFormat <> "d-mmm-yy" Or Cell.NumberFormat <> "dd-mmm-yy" Then
    Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
End If
```

I've tried forcing a ' into the cell value with

```
If Left(Cell.Value, 1) = "0" Then
    Cell.Value = "'" & Cell.Value
    Debug.Print Cell.Value
End If
```

But I don't appear to be having much luck. I'm trying to build a bit of a catch all solution that doesn't require anything in the spreadsheet to be changed as more information is added by other users.

Edit: Is there a way to detect a cell is already formatted as Date, and if so avoid overwriting it as Text? As a continuation of that to save time down the road, only mark it as Text if it's not already AND it's not a Date either.

Edit 2: Example - One work sheet would have rows such as
ABCD '012345 TL PT1234 NS CA
ABCD 112345  TL PT1235 NS CA
ACBD 0890    TL PT1238 NS CA

while another one would look more like

ABCD DR ROBB Bob Robertson Passport CA M 1/12/1990(Displayed as 1-Dec-90) AA1234501 CA ROBER0123456789 NS CA

Comment: What is the data type of the cells which contain leading zeros?

Comment: If you want to preserve leading zeros in numbers, just make sure that the cell has a custom format of `0000` (as many zeros as required).

Comment: @AAA General with ' leads and Text without, but new entries may not be formatted as Text by other users and I don't want numbers getting deleted by accident.

Comment: @MichalRosa Unfortunately, the number of zeroes (and number of digits) varies from anywhere between one to fourteen. I was also concerned that with mixed data, a straight Format might cause issues.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of some examples as well as the formula bar for a specific cell so we can see the full picture?

Comment: You can Also try **IsDate** function available in VBA to check if the cell contains a date instead of trying different formats as in your question. https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isdate.php

Comment: IsDate is not that reliable since there are a lot of values that will return false positives.

Comment: A false positive in this case isn't too bad. I suppose I could build in an interrupt that asks the user to confirm if the leading character is also a 0 or a '. @FrankBall Would you have another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other issues and providing sample data wpul;d help explain your situation but I'll start with the following.

```
If Cell.NumberFormat <> "d-mmm-yy" Or Cell.NumberFormat <> "dd-mmm-yy" Then
    Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
End If
```

You've fallen into a common logic 'hole'. Using the `Or` operator here is wrong. If a cell's number format is `d-mmm-yy` then it isn't `dd-mmm-yy` and vise versa. Additionally, any other number format is neither. In essence, every cell's number format regardless of what it is will not be one of the options so the test is always true. You want the `And` operator.

```
If Cell.NumberFormat <> "d-mmm-yy" AND Cell.NumberFormat <> "dd-mmm-yy" Then
    Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
End If
```

The above states that the number format cannot be **either** "d-mmm-yy" or "dd-mmm-yy".

However, a cell's .NumberFormat property could be *General* and still be a true date. To bypass this shortcoming, the `IsDate` function has been mentioned. This relies upon the regional information attached to a cell's default `.Value` property (not the `.Text` or `.Value2` properties).

```
If NOT ISDATE(Cell.Value) Then
    Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
End If
```

I've found `IsDate` to be fairly reliable even when testing text that only look like dates.

Q. If the cells with the leading zeroes are not formatted as text and do not have custom number formats that force leading zeroes, what is keeping the leading zeroes there in the first place?

Comment: For most entries, it appears that it's just a ' entered before the first zero. When the macro runs over the cell's value with the Trim, the apostrophe gets dropped for whatever reason followed by the zeroes behind it. Could IsDate and the  .NumberFormat checks be combined into something pretty much bulletproof? Thanks for the help!